Calculator Bit shift anomaly
I use gnome Calculator 41.1 to calc
3F<<10

Calculator says 0x3F0000
But I expect 0xFC00
Is it Calculator bug?
P.S. 3F<<9<<1 gives me what I expect 0xFC00.


Would it make sense to you if you read 10 as 10 in base 16, so 16 in base 10?

Note
3F<<10

Means 0x3F<<0x10 or 63<<16.
